# AjaxBegin form and DataAnnotation don't work

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a BeginForm with DataAnnotation on the model but they don't work properly.

model.cs

```
public class modelx
{
 .....
 [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Time_Step is required"]
 public String time_step_serialization { get; set; }
 .....
{
```

view.cs

```
<script text="text/javascript">
  function OnSuccess() {
  windows.location.href = '@Url.Action(.....);
}
</script>
<table class....>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(.........., new AjaxOptions() 
    {
     ....
     OnSuccess="OnSuccess"
    }))
    {
       @Html.ValidationSummary()
       <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.time_step_serialization)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.time_step_serialization)
       </td>
       .....
       </td>
    }
</table>
```

Controller.cs
I don't want to check nothing server side.

I setted the right configuration on the web.config and I imported the right libraries js:

1. jquery-1.7.1.min.js
2. jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
3. jquery.validate.js
4. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

What is the problem?

The html generated at runtime for the field is:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Time_step is required" id="time_step_serialization" name="time_step_serialization" type="text" value>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="time_step_serialization" data_valmsg_replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Is the view partial, loaded via Ajax?
Also, on a side note, your form is inside a table, that's an interesting concept...

Comment: @HenkMollema my validation is not working! When I submit the form I can do it even if the field is empty!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **valid** before sending data.

```
function save(){
  var valid  = $("#FormName").valid();
  if (!valid) return false;

  // post data
}
```